# MySql: Changing the source table in a complex if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I'm not sure if this is possible. But I have the following sql that inserts some values to the `product_filter` table based on what the special price of a product is.

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)
SELECT product_id,
  (CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
  WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
  WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
  WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
  WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
  WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
  WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
  ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
FROM product_special;
```

I'd like to modify the above script so if there is no special price set for a product, it just reads the regular price from the main `product` table. Since this will be run on a large database of products, I'd like to possibly combine both scripts instead of me manually running a different script on certain products.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: when you say `no special price set`, does it mean that the product is not present in `product_special` table? or its `0/Null`?

Comment: That means the product does not exist in the product_special table.

Comment: and all the products that exist in `product_special` also exist in `product` table?

Comment: if the product doesnt exist in `product_special`, get the product details from `product` table. this means you are updating every product from `product` table. so why dont you change the table to `products`?

Comment: Because I first need to get the 'special' price from the product_special table, if there is no special price, then I need to look at the product table to get the regular price. The special price does not exist in the product table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO product_filter (product_id,filter_id)

  SELECT product_id,
  (CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
  WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
  WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
  WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
  WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
  WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
  WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
  ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
  FROM product_special
  union
  SELECT product_id,
  (CASE WHEN price < 100 then 1
  WHEN price >= 100 AND price < 500 then 2
  WHEN price >= 500 AND price < 1000 then 3
  WHEN price >= 1000 AND price < 1500 then 4
  WHEN price >= 1500 AND price < 2000 then 5
  WHEN price >= 2000 AND price < 2500 then 50
  WHEN price >= 2500 AND price < 3000 then 6
  ELSE 51 END) AS filter_id
  FROM product where product_id not in
  (select product_id from product_special)
```

The above query assumes that you have `product_id` and `price` (as standard/regular price) columns in the `product` table. The idea here is to get all the existing products from the `product_special` table and their **special prices** and to adds to it the products that are not there in the `product_special` table but are there in the `product` table along with their **standard/regular prices**.

Comment: one more question: Looks like every product can have multiple special prices (running on different dates), is it possible to tweak that sql code so when it reads from the special table, it always reads the most current one? (the fields are product_special_is, product_id, price, date_start, date_end, priority)